# Firebase keepSynced does not synchronize the data immediately

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase for an iOS app. As the title says, I currently have a problem with keepSynced. It does not synchronize the data immediately.

For example, when I receive a push notification saying that a comment has been posted, the user opens the app and he's taken to a post where the comments are loaded. Now, if the app was not in background, it will have to call .keepSynced on certain children. Although this call happens before the comments are loaded, there is still not enough time, so the comments are loaded locally, missing the last ones.

The same thing happens when the user opens the app and the app and refreshes the feed. The first refresh is being done locally, missing the latest posts. After a few seconds, the .keepSynced method finally kicks in, and I can query the online DB.

I currently call .keepSynced in the appDelegate: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. In both cases mentioned above, I am using .observeSingleEventOfType. 
My question is, is there a different way to tell firebase to keep certain children always synchronized? In database rules, maybe? 
Other thoughts, suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem, i solved it disabling the persistenceEnabled feature.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `keepSynced(true)` on a node ensures that the Firebase Database client will synchronize that node whenever it has a connection to the database servers. There is no built-in API to keep a node synchronized when there is no such connection.

Comment: So what you're saying is that it loads offline data because the connection to the servers wasn't established yet? 
How do people usually get past this? Should I just delay the refresh until the connection is established?

Comment: I normally simply make sure that my UI shows the "most recent known value". So initially it shows the value from cache and it then updates when the server sync happened. If you want to skip showing the initial value, you can [listen for `.info/connected` to become `true`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is there any way I can configure the Realtime Database to use old data ONLY if nothing has changed, and use new data ONLY if something has changed? That's what I thought enabling persistence means, per the docs, but apparently it doesn't work that way. Thanks for the insights all over SO!

Comment: There's no configuration option for this behavior. Disk persistence and once/single-value-event-listeners just don't mix. Note that is better to open a new post for a new question, even when you think it's related to something else (in which case you can provide links in your question).